# Intermittent issue with query builder - Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In DebugKit, when I click on Variables, the only thing I see is:

```
Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
```

For instance, the entire code of my `index` function:

```
$data = $this->Seasons->find()
->where(['Seasons.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')]);

foreach($data as $season){
    $s = $season->id;

    $leagues = $this->Leagues->find()->innerJoinWith('Games', function ($q) use($s) {
            return $q->where(['Games.season_id' => $s]);
        }
    )
    ->where(['Leagues.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
    ->distinct(['Leagues.name'])
    ->order(['Leagues.name']);

    foreach($leagues as $league){
        $l = $league->id;

        $gametypes = $this->GameTypes->find()->innerJoinWith('Games', function ($q) use($s, $l) {
            return $q->where([
                    'Games.season_id' => $s,
                    'Games.league_id' => $l 
                ]);
            }
        )
        ->distinct(['GameTypes.sort_order'])
        ->order(['GameTypes.sort_order']);

        //set values to data
        $league["game_types"] = $gametypes;

    }
    //set values to data
    $season['leagues'] = $leagues;
}

$this->set(compact('data'));
```

This is an intermittent issue for me. In some cases, I can see DebugKit's variables just fine, others this error comes along and I have to use `debug()` to see the content of the variable.

**Edit #1**

Cake version: '3.3.10'

**Edit #2**

Code replaced by something that actually does not work. Previous code, it turns out, was working. This, does not.

I'm starting to suspect that this issue crops up whenever I attempt to build Query objects and populate keys with other Query objects?

**Edit #3**

I think I found the solution. If I call `toArray()` in all queries, `DebugKit` will show me the actual content, not the error.

I think my suspicion in Edit #2 was right. That, appending what are essentially Closures into other Closure was what `DebugKit` didn't like? The question begs, anything wrong with calling `toArray()` everywhere like I am?

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP! Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`), and in this case the debug kit version too (`vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: The error message posted is what I see when I click on Variables in DebugKit. No stack trace either. The page is rendered properly, I just can't see the content of the variable and it displays that message.

Comment: Normally every error should be logged together with a stacktrace... maybe debug kit explicitly swallows it. In any case, your debug kit version is still unknown. Also try it with your dependencies (CakePHP as well as debug kit) upgraded to the latest possible version (the latest CakePHP in the `3.3` branch is `3.3.15` and the latest compatible debug kit version is `3.9.3`).

Comment: I think I found the solution... needed to call toArray() everywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to call `toArray()` in all my queries.